# How to split a file based on 2 or more column values

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to split a file base on 2 column values.

Able to split a file based on one column

```
awk -F\| '{print>$1}' file1
```

Data Needs to be split based on column 2nd and 5th ( If column2 = 3 AND column5=M)

```
A1|3|100|20|M 
A1|5|101|20|N 
A1|5|101|30|M 
A1|3|105|20|O
B1|3|150|5|M
A1|3|106|20|Q
A1|5|101|20|N
A1|5|101|30|Q
A1|5108|20|O
B1|3|150|5|M


Output : File 1

A1|5|101|20|N
A1|5|101|30|M
A1|3|105|20|O
A1|3|106|20|Q
A1|5|101|20|N
A1|5|101|30|Q
A1|5108|20|O

Output: File 2

A1|3|100|20|M
B1|3|150|5|M
B1|3|150|5|M
```

Comment: not sure what your issue is, does `if ($2==3 && $5 == "M") { print ....}` help?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file1 
A1|3|100|20|M 
A1|5|101|20|N 
A1|5|101|30|M 
A1|3|105|20|O
B1|3|150|5|M
A1|3|106|20|Q
A1|5|101|20|N
A1|5|101|30|Q
A1|5108|20|O
B1|3|150|5|M
```

Try this:

```
awk -F\| '{print>$2$5}' file1
```

Which gives me:

```
ls -l
total 120
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  26 Jun 21 12:22 3M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  15 Jun 21 12:22 3M 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  14 Jun 21 12:22 3O
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  14 Jun 21 12:22 3Q
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  13 Jun 21 12:22 5108
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  15 Jun 21 12:22 5M 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  14 Jun 21 12:22 5N
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  15 Jun 21 12:22 5N 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  14 Jun 21 12:22 5Q
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink 140 Jun 21 12:16 file1
```